# Trac standalone reading htpasswd file, but still says Authentication information not available

Tags: configuration, trac, htpasswd, synology

I am having some problems correctly configuring my trac server.

I'm running Tracd 0.12.1 on a Synology DS411. I've followed [this guide](http://darenatwork.blogspot.dk/2011/11/how-to-install-trac-on-synology-ds2011_11.html), I can browse the issues in trac, but if I try to log in, it tells me the following error:

> ## Trac Error
>
> Authentication information not available. Please refer to the installation documentation.

The Log file says about the same:

```
2012-10-24 10:11:04,617 Trac[main] DEBUG: Dispatching <Request "GET '/login'">
2012-10-24 10:11:04,624 Trac[api] INFO: Synchronized '' repository in 0.01 seconds
2012-10-24 10:11:04,627 Trac[main] WARNING: HTTPInternalError: 500 Trac Error (Authentication information not available. Please refer to the <a href="/redaktion/wiki/TracInstall#ConfiguringAuthentication" title="Configuring Authentication">installation documentation</a>.)
2012-10-24 10:11:04,628 Trac[session] DEBUG: Retrieving session for ID '70d0293ad5b390acc86439b2'
2012-10-24 10:11:04,635 Trac[chrome] DEBUG: Prepare chrome data for request
2012-10-24 10:11:04,646 Trac[perm] DEBUG: No policy allowed anonymous performing TRAC_ADMIN on None
2012-10-24 10:11:04,647 Trac[perm] DEBUG: No policy allowed anonymous performing PERMISSION_GRANT on None
2012-10-24 10:11:04,648 Trac[perm] DEBUG: No policy allowed anonymous performing PERMISSION_REVOKE on None
2012-10-24 10:11:04,649 Trac[perm] DEBUG: No policy allowed anonymous performing TICKET_ADMIN on None
2012-10-24 10:11:04,650 Trac[perm] DEBUG: No policy allowed anonymous performing VERSIONCONTROL_ADMIN on None
2012-10-24 10:11:04,654 Trac[perm] DEBUG: No policy allowed anonymous performing TICKET_CREATE on None
2012-10-24 10:11:04,664 Trac[perm] DEBUG: No policy allowed anonymous performing EMAIL_VIEW on None
```

I start the server using the following command:

```
/opt/bin/tracd -d -p 8888 --basic-auth='"*",/volume1/svn/svn-auth-file,"Frederik Trac"' /volume1/trac-env/frederik
```

If I change the svn-auth-file path to an invalid one, I get a file not found error, so I gather it's not related to a missing/bad auth file.

The htpasswd file works fine when I test it via HTTP, using apache.

This is my trac.ini:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

[attachment]
max_size = 41943040
render_unsafe_content = false

[browser]
color_scale = True
downloadable_paths = /trunk, /branch/*, /tags/*
hide_properties = svk:merge
intermediate_color =
intermediate_point =
newest_color = (255, 136, 136)
oldest_color = (136, 136, 255)
oneliner_properties = trac:summary
render_unsafe_content = false
wiki_properties = trac:description

[changeset]
max_diff_bytes = 10000000
max_diff_files = 0
wiki_format_messages = true

[components]
componentdependencies.componentdependency.componentdependencyplugin = enabled
componentdependencies.test.foobartest = enabled
componentdependencies.test.testdependencyplugin = enabled
ticketsidebarprovider.ticketsidebar.ticketsidebarprovider = enabled
tracopt.mimeview.enscript.enscriptrenderer = enabled
tracopt.mimeview.php.phprenderer = enabled
tracopt.perm.authz_policy.authzpolicy = enabled
tracopt.perm.config_perm_provider.extrapermissionsprovider = enabled
tracopt.ticket.commit_updater.committicketreferencemacro = enabled
tracopt.ticket.commit_updater.committicketupdater = enabled
tracopt.ticket.deleter.ticketdeleter = enabled
#trac.web.auth.LoginModule = disabled
acct_mgr.web_ui.LoginModule = disabled
acct_mgr.web_ui.RegistrationModule = disabled
acct_mgr.admin.AccountManagerAdminPanel = enabled

webadmin.* = enabled

[inherit]
plugins_dir =
templates_dir =

[logging]
log_file = trac.log
log_level = DEBUG
log_type = none

[milestone]
stats_provider = DefaultTicketGroupStatsProvider

[mimeviewer]
enscript_modes = text/x-dylan:dylan:4
enscript_path = enscript
max_preview_size = 262144
mime_map = text/x-dylan:dylan,text/x-idl:ice,text/x-ada:ads:adb
php_path = php
pygments_default_style = trac
pygments_modes =
tab_width = 8

[notification]
admit_domains =
always_notify_owner = true
always_notify_reporter = false
always_notify_updater = true
ignore_domains =
mime_encoding = base64
smtp_always_bcc =
smtp_always_cc =
smtp_default_domain =
smtp_enabled = true
smtp_from = noreply@example.com
smtp_from_name = Trac Meister
smtp_port = 25
smtp_replyto = noreply@example.com
smtp_server = localhost
smtp_subject_prefix =
ticket_subject_template = $prefix $summary
use_public_cc = false
use_short_addr = false
use_tls = false

[project]
admin =
descr = Frederik Trac
footer = Visit the Trac open source project at<br /><a href="http://trac.edgewall.org/">http://trac.edgewall.org/</a>
icon = common/trac.ico
name = Frederik Trac
url =

[query]
default_anonymous_query = status!=closed&cc~=$USER
default_query = status!=closed&owner=$USER
items_per_page = 100

[report]
items_per_page = 100
items_per_page_rss = 0

[revisionlog]
default_log_limit = 100

[roadmap]
stats_provider = DefaultTicketGroupStatsProvider

[search]
min_query_length = 3

[svn]
branches = trunk,branches/*
tags = tags/*

[ticket]
default_cc =
default_component = Upload
default_description =
default_keywords =
default_milestone =
default_owner =
default_priority = mellem
default_resolution = FÃ¦rdig
default_severity =
default_summary =
default_type =
default_version =
max_description_size = 262144
preserve_newlines = default
restrict_owner = false
workflow = ConfigurableTicketWorkflow

[ticket-custom]
estimatedhours = text
estimatedhours.label = Estimated Hours
estimatedhours.value = 0
#kategori = select
#kategori.options = Udvikling|Drift
#kategori.value = Drift
totalhours = text
totalhours.label = Total Hours
totalhours.value = 0
sideid = text
sideid.label = Side ID
deadline = text
deadline.label = Deadline

[ticket-workflow]
accept = new,assigned,accepted,reopened -> accepted
accept.operations = set_owner_to_self
accept.permissions = TICKET_MODIFY
leave = * -> *
leave.default = 1
leave.operations = leave_status
reassign = new,assigned,accepted,reopened -> assigned
reassign.operations = set_owner
reassign.permissions = TICKET_MODIFY
reopen = closed -> reopened
reopen.operations = del_resolution
reopen.permissions = TICKET_CREATE
resolve = new,assigned,accepted,reopened -> closed
resolve.operations = set_resolution
resolve.permissions = TICKET_MODIFY

[timeline]
abbreviated_messages = true
changeset_collapse_events = false
changeset_long_messages = false
changeset_show_files = 0
default_daysback = 30
max_daysback = 90
newticket_formatter = oneliner
ticket_show_details = true

[trac]
authz_file =
authz_module_name =
auto_reload = False
base_url =
check_auth_ip = true
database = sqlite:db/trac.db
default_charset = iso-8859-15
htdocs_location =
ignore_auth_case = false
mainnav = wiki,timeline,roadmap,tickets,newticket,search
metanav = login,logout,prefs,help,about
permission_policies = DefaultPermissionPolicy, LegacyAttachmentPolicy
permission_store = DefaultPermissionStore
repository_dir =
repository_type = svn
show_email_addresses = false
timeout = 20
use_base_url_for_redirect = False

[wiki]
ignore_missing_pages = false
render_unsafe_content = false
split_page_names = false

[account-manager]
password_store = HttpAuthStore
authentication_url = http://192.168.10.11:8000/trac
```

Would anyone be able to tell me what I'm missing?